# How to sort columns independently?

Tags: text-processing, sort, columns

```
$ sort -t $'\t' -k 1rn,1 -k 2,2rn -k 3f,4 listaprezzi

2050        900           bananas     5
1905        700           grapes      17
250         4000          oranges     10
230         9200          figs        4
220         5000          lemons      10
200         8000          pears       8
```

I want to sort 1st column of `listaprezzi` numerically in reverse (option `rn`), 2nd also `rn`, and third alphabetically (`f`). What is the correct command?

I've tried many ways but having no success.

Comment: If you want to sort all three columns at the same time (rearrange data) then it is impossible with pure sort, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Can you show us what you expect the output to look like given you sample data? It's unclear what you're expecting sort to do here. If you're expecting sort to operate on the columns individually I do not believe it can do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question you want to rearrange your data, i.e. independently sort (up or down) different fields of the same row. You cannot do that with bare `sort`, you need to use additional tools, for example with the help of `awk` and `paste` you can write the following:

```
$ paste <(awk '{print $1}' listaprezzi | sort -nr) <(awk '{print $2}' \
  listaprezzi | sort -nr) <(awk '{print $3}' listaprezzi | sort) <(awk \
  '{print $4}' listaprezzi)
```

And the result is

```
2050    9200    bananas   5
1905    8000    figs      17
250     5000    grapes    10
230     4000    lemons    4
220     900     oranges   10
200     700     pears     8
```